# High Low: Computer guesses your number

Tags: python

all. I'm quite new to programming, and I'm trying to figure out why my code isn't working properly. It runs fine up until you tell the computer whether or not its first guess is too high (h), or too low (l). If, say, the guess is too high, and tell the computer that, each guess after will continue guessing lower, regardless of whether or not you enter too low (l). It happens the other way around as well. Hopefully someone can help. Here's the code!

```
import random
import time

print "Think of a number between 1 and 100 and I'll try and guess it."
time.sleep(2)
print "Let me know if my guess is too (h)igh, too (l)ow, or (c)orrect."
time.sleep(2)

guess = int(raw_input("Pick your number between 1-100: "))

low = 1
high = 100
tries = 0
compguess = random.randrange(low, high)
h = compguess > guess
l = compguess < guess
c = compguess == guess

while compguess != guess:
    tries += 1
    print "Is it", compguess

if h:
    raw_input ()
    new_high = (compguess - 1)
    compguess = random.randint(low, new_high)

elif l:
    raw_input ()
    new_low = (compguess + 1)
    compguess = random.randint(new_low, high)

elif c:
    raw_input ()
    print("The computer guessed your number of: ", guess)
```

Forgive the spacing. I'm not quite sure how to copy it properly.

Comment: Can you please fox your indentation.

Answer (score 2):

The `raw_input()` function returns a value. If you don't assign the return value to a variable or otherwise do something with it, the value returned is simply discarded by Python.

You probably want something like:

```
print "Is it", compguess
answer = raw_input()
if answer == "h":
    ...
elif answer == "l":
    ...
```

That way, you prompt the user for input, wait for the user to type something, then act upon what the user typed.

You also don't need the `h`, `l`, or `c` local variables. They don't actually serve a purpose in your code.

Finally, why do you ask the user to tell the computer what number the user is thinking of? Isn't the point of this exercise to get the computer to *guess* the user's number, without knowing what the result is?